# how to use appium to get the context of an already running app?

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

Basically i want to write a E2E test for my app as an SDK app used by another app.

I have an android app `A` that invokes another android app `B`.

I want to write test that starts `app A`, clicks on a button which opens `app B`.

I then want to click a button in `app B`. Which terminate `app B` and return the focus to `app A` with some data.

Is it possible to get the context of `app B` when it's open by `app A`?

Meaning to be able to click on elements from `app B` even though it was open by an intent from `app A` and not open by appium?

Usually I open an app myself and get it context from that.

like this:

```
AndroidDriver AndroidDriver = new AndroidDriver( "http://localhost:53761/wd/hub" , capabilitiesObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by get the context? If you're talking about switching between a web view or a native app, then that operation is done on the driver itself.

If you're talking about having the ability to interact with elements on the screen for `app B`, then you can also do that. I currently open a separate app using adb, and Appium seems to recognize whatever view is on the screen.

Comment: I have updated my q. hope it's clear now.
Basically i want to write a E2E test for my app as an SDK app used by another app.
so by `context` I mean to be able to click on elements from `app B` even though it was open by an intent from `app A` and not open by appium?

Comment: OK, in that case I answered that. It's the second block in my answer. I currently use an intent through adb to open up my app B while I'm inside of app A. This works fine to interact with app B.